# Bash issues with osascript GUI commands

Tags: macos, bash, applescript, osascript

I am trying to automate the process of launching an application in OSX and typing an administrator password at a security agent prompt. I was hoping to avoid the use of AppleScript GUI scripting however the underlying cause of the admin prompt is so convoluted and complicated I just won't go there.

Below is the script which works perfectly when run locally by an OSX administrator. Ie. from terminal `adminaccount# /usr/local/bin/ReasonScript.sh`

```
#/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/osascript <<EOF
launch application "Reason"
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until (exists window 1 of process "SecurityAgent")
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        tell window 1 of process "SecurityAgent"
            tell scroll area 1 of group 1
                set value of text field 1 to "adminaccount"
                set value of text field 2 to "adminpassword"
            end tell
            click button "OK" of group 2
        end tell
    end tell
EOF

exit 0
```

**The Problem**

I need to execute this script as a root user (not great I know but its how our deployment software does it). So I try it like `root# /usr/local/bin/ReasonScript.sh` and I get the following error

```
105:106: syntax error: Expected “,” but found “"”. (-2741)
```

I have gone through the script but I am not expert at AppleScript but I can't find this syntax error. But at the same time I do not expect this to work as the ROOT user doesn't have a GUI to access so maybe this is part of that failure.

Then I try and assume the local users permissions from root... ie `root# sudo -u adminaccount /usr/local/bin/ReasonScript.sh`

Unfortunately i get the following

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
```

A thousand appologies if Stackoverflow is not the right place for this question. I'm so confused I don't know how to troubleshoot this further. Is it AppleScript, is it osascript, is it BASH or is it the administration structure of OSX.

I appreciate all the assistance I can get with this pickle.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

```
osascript will look for the script in one of the following three places:

 1.   Specified line by line using -e switches on the command line.

 2.   Contained in the file specified by the first filename on the command
      line.  This file may be plain text or a compiled script.

 3.   Passed in using standard input.  This works only if there are no
      filename arguments; to pass arguments to a STDIN-read script, you
      must explicitly specify ``-'' for the script name.
```

If you are going to use a heredoc, you will have to use the third option. Otherwise, you can either have an applescipt file or run it line by line with -e.